# Wrapping multiple recurring elements with jQuery wrapAll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have been looking into a solution for this for ages. Basically I have a repeating structure as follows:

```
<div class="article">
    <div>
    </div>
    <h2>
    </h2>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="article">
    <div>
    </div>
    <h2>
    </h2>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I need to wrap the last three child elements of .article in a div e.g.

```
<div class="article">
    <div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>
        </h2>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried jQuery .before() and .after() but the elements close before I can call them both. This was my last ditch effort:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready( function () {
        var items = $(".article > *");
        for(var i = 1; i < items.length; i+=3) {
            items.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
        };
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This works fine for the first .article but ruins the rest of the code.

Real life example here:

http://www.blanketmedia.com.au/Cruise/hotnews.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the elements, select the children, remove the first, and wrap them.

```js
$(".article").each( function () {
    $(this).children().slice(1).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
});
```

```css
.article { background: yellow; }
.wrapper { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">
    <div>1
    </div>
    <h2>2
    </h2>
    <div>3
    </div>
    <div>4
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="article">
    <div>5
    </div>
    <h2>6
    </h2>
    <div>7
    </div>
    <div>8
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. I was clearly overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('.article *:nth-child(3)').wrap("<div class='wrapper'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```js
$('.article').each(function(){
  var articleChildren = $(this).children();
  var lastThreeElements = articleChildren.slice(Math.max(articleChildren.length - 3, 1));
  lastThreeElements.wrapAll('<div class="wrapper">');
});
```

```css
.article { background: yellow; }
.wrapper { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">
    <div>Div 1
    </div>
    <h2>Header 1
    </h2>
    <div>Inner Div 1
    </div>
    <div>Inner Div 2
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="article">
    <div>Div 1
    </div>
    <h2>Header 1
    </h2>
    <div>Inner Div 1
    </div>
    <div>Inner Div 2
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks krix this works too. Is there a more efficient of the two?

Comment: The only difference is that I slice all but the last three elements out of the array before wrapping. So it should not matter how many other elements you have in your div before the "last three" elements.